# Django access array inside dict in template

Tags: python, django

When I try and access a simple dict in django:

```
{'The Batman': [{'datetime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'id': '1'},{'datetime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'id': '1'}],
'Ice Age': [{'datetime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'id': '1'}, {'datetime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'id':    '1'}]}
```

I use this loop to access the keys:

```
{% for film in data %}
...Code here
{% endfor %}
```

but then when I go to access the values, it returns nothing. I am accessing the values as follows:

```
{% for showing in data.film %}
...Code here
{% endfor %}
```

I am printing out the data to my screen every time, so I know there is data there, because the headings register too. Unsure what is happening or what I am doing wrong.

Fairly new to Django so pls be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `.items` to loop over a dict, almost just like you'd do in plain Python code:

```
{% for film, showings in data.items %}
   <h1>{{ film }}</h1>
   <ul>
   {% for showing in showings %}
      <li>{{ showing.datetime }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: AMAZING, THANK YOU!!! Will accept when it allows me to!!

Answer (score 0):

Data is a dictionary so you need to run over it’s items.

Like this:

```
{% for key, values in data.items %}
```